# Should I move out of my consulting company without informing my boss?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, ethics

I am currently working in Europe as a consultant in my native country.
I have been looking for a new job in Asia for several months, and I have told it to my boss. He told me he would try to start a business with some companies implanted in Asia for me.

For my part, I had two options :

- Passive way : wait for my company to find me a new role in Asia.
- Active way : independently contact some companies.

During the last call we had, I admitted I had already looked for some jobs outside of his consulting company, although in an ideal world, I would rather work in Asia for him. He was a little angry about it and told me he was dealing with companies implanted in Asia only for me (I am currently the only consultant who wants to find a role in Asia), so the only thing I had to do when I see a job offer would be to transfer it to him, and to not pursue it by myself.

Now I have 2 options :

1. Passive way, and no active way : I wait and I don't contact any companies independently, talking to my boss about the companies in which I find some job offers.
2. Passive and active way : I wait but I also contact companies independently, then I suppose I shouldn't talk to my boss about the companies where I am likely to apply.

Well, that's actually quite the same options than the two I exposed above.

To summarize my thoughts, my first priority is to find a job or a mission that I like, no matter if I do it with or without my current company. But I am not sure I have more chances to find a job by applying directly **instead** of collaborating with my boss, and I also don't want to deliver a low blow to him.

Combining the personal and diplomatic way, what would you do ?

Comment: Pretty sure "postulate" doesn't mean what you think it does :-)

Comment: Postulate isn't the correct term to use here.  Do you mean to carry out the activity of searching for a job? Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: A false friend, in French *postuler* means *to apply* ^^'

Comment: Sorry, I meant _to apply_ indeed. Thank you @PhilipKendall

Answer (score 4):

**Definitely solution 2 !**

You can not solely rely on your boss to find you a job where he has no business implemented, if you find a good position in Asia sign the contract there and resign from your current company.

Comment: You should change 'not only rely on your boss' to 'not solely rely on your boss' to clarify the meaning of the sentence.  My attempt to edit this failed because it was under six characters

Comment: And +1 for a good answer

Answer (score 0):

It is  life and your career, shape it the way you want. Find opportunities for yourself, your boss doesn't give a damn if he is not happy that your are finding a way to do something which you want to do. Don't bother to even spend a minute on diplomatic way. There are more than enough opportunities, you don't need him or his company to make things happen for you.